# Error: googleapi: Error 400: The specified location constraint is not valid., invalid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops

I am getting the following error when trying to use Terraform to create a new GCP Project and Create a Bucket -
`Error: googleapi: Error 400: The specified location constraint is not valid., invalid │  │   with google_storage_bucket.project-data, │   on storage.tf line 5, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "project-data": │    5: resource "google_storage_bucket" "project-data" {`

This is the bucket code

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "project-data" {
  depends_on    = [google_project_service.storage-component_api]
  project       = google_project.project.project_id
  name          = join("", [google_project.project.project_id, "-project-data"])
  location      = "us-center1"
  storage_class = "REGIONAL"
}
```

Tried to change the name, added storage class, searched trough the internet but found nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a quick glance, you are specifying a location that does not exist. You have to use a [valid location](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations).I assume you meant `US-CENTRAL1`

Comment: I've been staring this for hours and it is a typo at the end..Thank you!